photodiode amplifier circuitry with high gain
I am designing a very sensitive photodiode current amplifier circuit that will finally be read by a ADC for a sensor application. We know the light incidence frequency on the sensor which we keep at about 1 Hz. While the simulation works well, in practice my voltage levels are off. Here are the details:
I have gain in at least three stages. In the transimdepance stage, I have a gain of 1M. I use a differential with unity gain for noise rejection. In the next subsequent stages I apply gains of 100 and 100 respectively.
The high passes are designed at ~0.5 Hz, and the low passes ~15 hz. ADA4891 has very low bias currents (~50pA) matching the photodiode dark current and is rail-rail . The filters were chosen to be very restricted to avoid sensor noises due to very high gain. (If we relax the low pass filters, very sharp peaks upto VCC is observed. )
However, the problem is this: The circuit does not have the designed gain. Infact, the differential(Instrumentation) voltage output is lower than its inputs (like fractional gain).
Any suggestions and advice is much appreciated.
Thanking you
Krishna


Do you have a capacitor across the Vref pins? There might be some noise there without it.

Have you tried to put a large resistor in between the RG pins of U6?

You need to state what gain you intended the circuit to have. You need to verify the gain after the 1st stage (divide and conquer).
